# pyimage4 error while trying to set image to 2nd window

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, user-interface, tkinter

im trying to set image to my 2nd window of tkinter which opens when i click on button
but it shows error
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist

```
def new_window():
    if(user.get()==username and passw.get()==password):
        window= Tk()
        window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0"%(w,h))
        image_new = Image.open("E:\\schoolmng\\try1.jpg")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_new)
        panel2 = Label(window, image=photo)
        panel2.pack()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("error","wrong password or username")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `window = Tk()` to `window = Toplevel()`. The reason why there is an error is because there is two instance of `Tk()` running, there should be not more than 1 instance of `Tk()` running. So replacing it with `Toplevel()` will fix this issue.

**TIP:**

- You will get an additional problem of no image displayed here, as the image will be garbage collected, to fix this you have to keep reference to the image, either by saying `global photo` on top of the function or `panel2.image = photo`. Saying either of this will fix the error.
- *Solution 1:*

```
def new_window():
    global photo
....
```

- *Solution 2:*

```
...
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_new)
panel2 = Label(window, image=photo)
panel2.image = photo
panel2.pack()
...
```

Hope your issues are solved, if any more errors, do let me know.

Cheers

Comment: no error now thanks but still no image on 2nd window

Comment: @Robin Ive updated the answer. Would appreciate if you could mark it as the answer

Comment: thanks it worked,i'm  new to stackoverflow so plz tell me how can i increase your points