# How to get two images on separate frames using Canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, background-image, tkinter-canvas

in the following code I am trying to put two images on two separate window frames using Canvas

```
PANEL_HEIGHT = 440
PANEL_WIDTH = 304
BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"
MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"

class window1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.panel = Tk()
        self.panel.geometry(f"{PANEL_WIDTH}x{PANEL_HEIGHT}")


        self.canvas = Canvas(self.panel,width=2*PANEL_WIDTH, height=2*PANEL_HEIGHT)
        canvas = self.canvas

        img = PhotoImage(file=BKG_IMG)
        canvas.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH,PANEL_HEIGHT,image=img)
        canvas.place(x=-(PANEL_WIDTH/2),y=-(PANEL_HEIGHT/2))

class window2:

    def __init__(self):
        self.panel = Tk()
        self.panel.geometry(f"{PANEL_WIDTH}x{PANEL_HEIGHT}")


        self.canvas = Canvas(self.panel, width=2 * PANEL_WIDTH, height=2 * PANEL_HEIGHT)
        canvas = self.canvas
        img = PhotoImage(file=MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG)
        canvas.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT, image=img)
        canvas.place(x=-(PANEL_WIDTH / 2), y=-(PANEL_HEIGHT / 2))

window1()
window2()
```

on calling these two classes I am getting "image 'pyimage2' doesn't exist" error

Absolute path of both the files are

D:\pyAut\pythonBootCamp\backgrounds\manage_acc_ui_bkg.png
D:\pyAut\pythonBootCamp\main.py

could any body tell how to accomplish the task????

Comment: You're calling `Tk()` more than use (you have to use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows, and you aren't saving a reference to your PhotoImage objects (so they will be immediately garbage-collected).

Comment: how to save reference to the PotoImage??

Comment: Search this site, there has been plenty questions already. Example: [my button in tkinter is not showing the image \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64768327/13382000) also [pyimage4 error while trying to set image to 2nd window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63799551/13382000)

Answer (score 1):

You have created Tk() twice: self.panel = Tk() avoid that.
move self.panel = Tk() to outside to share: panel = Tk().

Please try it:

```
from tkinter import *  

PANEL_HEIGHT = 440
PANEL_WIDTH = 304
BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"
MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"

panel = Tk()
panel.geometry(f"{PANEL_WIDTH}x{PANEL_HEIGHT}")

class window1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(panel,width=2*PANEL_WIDTH, height=2*PANEL_HEIGHT)
        canvas = self.canvas

        img = PhotoImage(file=BKG_IMG)
        canvas.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH,PANEL_HEIGHT,image=img)
        canvas.place(x=-(PANEL_WIDTH/2),y=-(PANEL_HEIGHT/2))

class window2:

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(panel, width=2 * PANEL_WIDTH, height=2 * PANEL_HEIGHT)
        canvas = self.canvas
        img = PhotoImage(file=MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG)
        canvas.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT, image=img)
        canvas.place(x=-(PANEL_WIDTH / 2), y=-(PANEL_HEIGHT / 2))

window1()
window2()
```

Comment: no, this destroys the Tk() application as I cancels the first window, and it gives error

Answer (score 1):

*Hope you are satisfied with the information given*

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

PANEL_HEIGHT = 440
PANEL_WIDTH = 304

main = tk.Tk()

BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"
MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"


class window1:
    window = tk.Toplevel(main)
    window.geometry(f"{PANEL_WIDTH}x{PANEL_HEIGHT}")
    window.title("Window 1")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BKG_IMG))
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=PANEL_WIDTH, height=PANEL_HEIGHT, background="white")
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT, image=img)


class window2:
    main.title("Window 2")
    main.geometry(f"{PANEL_WIDTH}x{PANEL_HEIGHT}")

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG))
    canvas = tk.Canvas(main, width=PANEL_WIDTH, height=PANEL_HEIGHT, background="white")
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT, image=img)


window1()
window2()

main.mainloop()
```

[image: output:]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `PhotoImage` of `tkinter` doesn't support `.png` format and it supports only `gif`,`ppm/pgm` format.
If you want to use `.png` format then you need to use PIL library.
Then I think that your image is getting totally wasted after your `window1` and `window2` instances are closed.
Thus, you need to add `self` before img.
Also, you are calling `Tk()` two times which is a problem.
Lastly, you are using similar names in both classes which is not good.
Thus after all editing your code will look  like.

```
from PIL import ImageTk
PANEL_HEIGHT = 440
PANEL_WIDTH = 304
BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"
MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG = "./backgrounds/Wireframe- welcome screen – 1.png"

panel = Tk()
panel.geometry(f"{PANEL_WIDTH}x{PANEL_HEIGHT}")

class window1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(panel,width=2*PANEL_WIDTH, height=2*PANEL_HEIGHT)
        canvas = self.canvas

        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=BKG_IMG)
        canvas.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH,PANEL_HEIGHT,image=self.img)
        canvas.place(x=-(PANEL_WIDTH/2),y=-(PANEL_HEIGHT/2))

class window2:

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas1 = Canvas(panel, width=2 * PANEL_WIDTH, height=2 * PANEL_HEIGHT)
        canvas1 = self.canvas1
        self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=MANAGE_ACC_BKG_IMG)
        canvas1.create_image(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT, image=self.img1)
        canvas1.place(x=-(PANEL_WIDTH / 2), y=-(PANEL_HEIGHT / 2))

window1()
window2()
panel.mainloop
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: although i solved my problem, but I always use png format and it works with PhotoImage

Comment: I think the above link has died I didn't know about `create_image` method of `canvas` so I searched for it on Google and found this and gave the anwer on its basis but I tested the code myself also on pycharm . Also I would like to know how you solved your problem

Comment: by using Toplevel() and frame instead of calling Tk() again and again